# PDF issue while reaching end of page

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, rendering, pdfbox

Well I'm having some troubles when creating new pages.

I get my data from a query.

Sorry if I post a lot of code, but it's all needed and I'm not sure how to do a MCVE as I'm pretty new at working with PDF.

This issue is:

Before writing next block of code I check current Y coord, I can achieve this, but when I need to create new Page and start writing again, well happens [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-z424N1EYicYkp1SXdESnRFcmM/edit?usp=sharing)

Here are the codes used in the PDF:

```
public float checkContentStream(float y) throws Exception {
    float newY = checkYCoord(y, 3, 10);
    if (newY == 700) {
        if (content != null) {
        content.close();
        }

        File file = new File(logoPath);
        PDJpeg logoImg = new PDJpeg(doc, new FileInputStream(file));
        PDPage page = new PDPage(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_LETTER);
        doc.addPage(page);
        content = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
        content.drawImage(logoImg, 50, 720);
        rHeader();
    }
    return newY;
    }
```

This method checks if reached BOTTOM MARGIN = 60

```
private float checkYCoord(float y, int lines, int space) {
    float newY = y;
    for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
        if ((newY - space) <= BOTTOM_MARGIN) {
        newY = 700f;
        return newY;
        } else {
        newY = newY - space;
        }
    }
    return y;
    }
```

This method does the same as 1st but used both, I know I shouldn't and must not use hardcoded values, like 10 or 3.

```
public float checkContentStream(float y, int lines, int space) throws Exception {
    float newY = checkYCoord(y, lines, space);
    if (newY == 700) {
        if (content != null) {
        content.close();
        }
        File file = new File(logoPath);
        PDJpeg logoImg = new PDJpeg(doc, new FileInputStream(file));
        PDPage page = new PDPage(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_LETTER);
        doc.addPage(page);
        content = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
        content.drawImage(logoImg, 50, 720);
        rHeader();
    }
}

public float rText(float x, float y, int space, String labelField, String value, int fieldSize) throws Exception {
    if(fieldSize == 1){
        return rText(x, y, space, labelField, value, FIELD_WIDTH, VALUE_WIDTH);
        }
    else{
        if(fieldSize == 2){
        return rText(x, y, space, labelField, value, FIELD_WIDTH, DESC_WIDTH);
        }
        else{
        return rText(x, y, space, labelField, value, FIELD_WIDTH, TEXT_WIDTH);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm almost sure the error comes from this method:

```
public float rText(float x, float y, int space, String labelField, String value, int fieldWidth, int valueWidth) throws Exception {
    PDFont font = PDType1Font.TIMES_BOLD;
    content.setFont(font, 9);
    float y1 = 0f;
    float y2 = 0f;
    //y = y >= 700 ? 700 : checkContentStream(y, 3, 10);
    if (value == null) {
        //y = checkYCoord(y, 1, 10);
        return rText(labelField, fieldWidth, x, y - 19, space, font, false);
        }else {
        //y = checkYCoord(y, 3, 10);
        y1 = rText(labelField, fieldWidth, x, y - 20, space, font, false);
        font = PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN;
        content.setFont(font, 9);
        y = checkYCoord(y, 3, 10); // Comment / Uncoment this line
        y2 = rText(value, valueWidth, x + fieldWidth + 10, y - 20, space, font, true);
        if (y1 >= y2) {
        return y2;
        } else {
        return y1;
        }
    }
}
```

This method paints text

```
private float rText(String text, int width, float x, float y, int space, PDFont font, boolean isValue) throws Exception {
    float newY = y;
    int rowHeight = 0;
    ArrayList<String> rowList = getRows(text, width, font);
    if(isValue){
        newY = checkContentStream(newY);
        newY = newY == 700 ? 680 : newY;
        for (String row : rowList) {
        if(rowHeight >= 10){
            newY = checkContentStream(newY - 10);
            newY = newY == 700 ? 680 : newY;
        }
        else{
            newY = checkContentStream(newY);
            newY = newY == 700 ? 680 : newY;
        }
        content.beginText();
        content.moveTextPositionByAmount(x, newY);
        content.drawString(row);
        content.endText();
        rowHeight = rowHeight + 10;
        }
    }
    else{
        newY = checkContentStream(newY, rowList.size(), space);
        newY = newY == 700 ? 680 : newY;
        for(String row : rowList){
        content.beginText();
        content.moveTextPositionByAmount(x, newY - rowHeight);
        content.drawString(row);
        content.endText();
        rowHeight = rowHeight + 10;
        }
        newY -= (rowHeight - 9);
    }
    return newY;
}
```

This method which is in another class brings data from query:

```
private float renderSubscriptionNew(PdfRenderingPC pdf, float y, SubscriptionNew sNew) throws Exception {
    DataResponse dr = dataSvc.buildResponse(folio, sNew, unitSvc);
    List<Data> dataList = dr.getDataList();

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    float y2[] = new float[3];
    for (Data data : dataList) {
        String labelField = constants.getString(data.getName());
        String value = getValue(data);
        float xCoord = 0;
        boolean getNewRow = false;
        int fieldSize = 1;
        switch (i) {
        case 0:
        case 4:
        xCoord = LEFT_MARGIN;
        break;
        case 1:
        case 5:
        xCoord = MIDDLE_COL;
        break;
        case 2:
        case 6:
        xCoord = RIGHT_COL;
        getNewRow = true;
        break;
        case 3:
        xCoord = LEFT_MARGIN;
        getNewRow = true;
        break;
        }
        if (getNewRow) {
        if(j == 0){
            y = pdf.rText(xCoord, y, 10, labelField, value, fieldSize);
        }
        else{
            y = pdf.rText(xCoord, y, 10, labelField, value, fieldSize);
            float min = y;
            for(int k = (j - 1); k >= 0; k--){
            if(y2[k] < min){
                min = y2[k];
            }
            }
            y = min;
            j = 0;
        }   
        } else {
            y2[j] = pdf.rText(xCoord, y, 10, labelField, value, fieldSize);
            j++;
        }
        i++;
}
```

Any help, guide, would be pretty apreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: Your `renderSubscriptionNew` iterates over `dataList`, and either three or one such list element are arranged next to each other. Thus, in case of three data elements next to each other, you must not switch pages during a call of `rtext` but have to already check the data triple in `renderSubscriptionNew` and switch page only once for it (*before* calling `rtext` for the first entry of the triple). I'm afraid your code requires quite some cleaning up.

Comment: @mkl so if I understood well what you're saying, it's I should remove all checkContentStream on rText, but for value, am I right? That way it will validate my Y coord once per row and for values it will check so in larger texts it will always make a page break.

Comment: Actually i doubt it is a good idea to check from inside rtext at all, i think the check should be where the code knows whether there are multiple data next next to each other or not, i.e. In renderSubscriptionNew. Maybe your idea suffices, though, i don't know.

Comment: @mkl thanks, I solved it with the 1st comment, I did it on 'renderSubscriptionNew' and it only checks when text is more than 2 lines, so it will create new pages in case text is larger than that. Shall I delete this post? since it has no answers and just comments?

Comment: *Shall I delete this post?* - well, instead of deleting it you could answer it yourself, posting your new `renderSubscriptionNew` code and a short explanation.

Comment: @mkl just posted answer, I just was busy and couldn't post it till today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [@mkl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774668/pdf-issue-while-reaching-end-of-page?noredirect=1#comment34731131_22774668) for his comment, I solved it like this:

I added the following code on 'renderSubscriptionNew'

```
if(visible){
    if (getNewRow) {
        if(j == 0){
        y = pdf.checkContentStream(y, 3, 10);
        y = pdf.rText(xCoord, y, 10, labelField, value, 
                  fieldSize);
        }
        else{
        y = pdf.rText(xCoord, y, 10, labelField, value, 
                  fieldSize);
        float min = y;
        for(int k = (j - 1); k >= 0; k--){
            if(y2[k] < min){
            min = y2[k];
            }
        }
        y = min;
        j = 0;
        }

    } else {
        if(j == 0){
        y = pdf.checkContentStream(y, 3, 10);
        }
        y2[j] = pdf.rText(xCoord, y, 10, labelField, value, 
                  fieldSize);
        j++;
    }
    }
    i++;
}
```

And this is rText (the last one):

```
private float rText(String text, int width, float x, float y, int space,
        PDFont font, boolean isValue) throws Exception {
float newY = y;
int rowHeight = 0;
ArrayList<String> rowList = getRows(text, width, font);
if(isValue){
    for (String row : rowList) {
    if(rowHeight >= 10){
        newY = checkContentStream(newY - 10);
        newY = newY == 700 ? 680 : newY;
    }
    else{
    }
    content.beginText();
    content.moveTextPositionByAmount(x, newY);
    content.drawString(row);
    content.endText();
    rowHeight = rowHeight + 10;
    }
}
else{
    for(String row : rowList){
    content.beginText();
    content.moveTextPositionByAmount(x, newY - rowHeight);
    content.drawString(row);
    content.endText();
    rowHeight = rowHeight + 10;
    }
    newY -= (rowHeight - 9);
}
return newY;
}
```