# PdfBox issue while changing page

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, rendering, pdfbox

I'm not a big fan of asking this kind of questions but well, it's been 3 whole days now trying to solve this bug on my code.

I know it's a logic problem and I know how to solve it in my mind, but when it comes to translate my ideas into code I just can't make it work as I want.

I'm working on a contract endorsement (a modification of a contract) which compares the data from 2 tables and if any of them has changed then it paints only that information.

Sometimes the information that changes such as conditions grows up or lowers in length, here's where the problem lies.

I made an algorithm which gets the minimum Y coord once it finished painting the information but when I change page Y coord must be reseted to `700f` and start painting again from there.

The code I'm using was first made by another programmer who's not here anymore, I don't know how to do an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with PDF's.

But here are the methods I think may help you helping me.

An example of how I compare and paint information on the PDF:

`sOffA` and `sOffE` are objects from a Class called `SubscriptionOffer` and `A` stands for `Agreement` while `E` for `Endorsement`. Endorsement is a copy of the table `Agreement` on MySQL but with the information modified. Probably this is irrelevant information, probably not.

```
if (!nullOrEmpty(sOffA.getGeneralConditions()) &&
    !nullOrEmpty(sOffE.getGeneralConditions())) {
    if (!getStringValue(sOffA.getGeneralConditions()).
    equals(getStringValue(sOffE.getGeneralConditions()))) {
    minYs[0] = pdf.rText(LEFT_MARGIN, y, 10, 
                 constants.generalConditions(),
                 getStringValue(sOffA.
                        getGeneralConditions()));

    minYs[1] = pdf.rText(HALF_PAGE, y, 10, 
                 constants.generalConditions(),
                 getStringValue(sOffE.
                        getGeneralConditions()));

    y = checkY(pdf, minYs);
    }
} else if (nullOrEmpty(sOffA.getGeneralConditions()) &&
       !nullOrEmpty(sOffE.getGeneralConditions())) {
    minYs[0] = pdf.rText(LEFT_MARGIN, y, 10, "", "");

    minYs[1] = pdf.rText(HALF_PAGE, y, 10, 
             constants.generalConditions(),
             getStringValue(sOffE.
                    getGeneralConditions()));

    y = checkY(pdf, minYs);
} else if (!nullOrEmpty(sOffA.getGeneralConditions()) &&
       nullOrEmpty(sOffE.getGeneralConditions())) {
    minYs[0] = pdf.rText(LEFT_MARGIN, y, 10, 
             constants.generalConditions(),
             getStringValue(sOffA.
                    getGeneralConditions()));

    minYs[1] = pdf.rText(HALF_PAGE, y, 10, "", "");

    y = checkY(pdf, minYs);
}
```

The array I use is this one:

```
private float[] minYs = new float[] {700, 700, 700, 700, 700, 700, 700,
                                     700, 700};
```

This is the method `checkY`, it checks which Y on the array (as seen above) is the lowest one, then it restarts the whole array back to 700f for all elements. And after that it checks if the space below the lowest Y coord is enough to paint next item.

```
private float checkY(PdfRenderingEndorsement pdf, float... ys) throws Exception {
    float y2 = getMinY(pdf, ys);
    for (int i = 0; i < ys.length; i++) {
        ys[i] = 700;
    }
    y2 = pdf.checkContentStream(y2, 5, 10);
    return y2;      
}
```

This method is where I guess my logic problem is, and as you can see I've tried diferent things, the original algorithm was only the `for-each` part then I've tried different things w/o success.

```
private float getMinY(PdfRenderingEndorsement pdf, float... ys) {
    float result = 700f;
    float lowest1 = 0, lowest2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ys.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ys.length; j++) {
        if (ys[j] > ys[i]) {
            float aux = ys[i];
            ys[i] = ys[j];
            ys[j] = aux;
            //lowest1 = ys[i];
            //lowest2 = ys[j];
        }
        }
    }
    if (ys.length > 1) {
        lowest1 = ys[0];
        lowest2 = ys[1];
    }
    LOGGER.trace("lowest1: " + lowest1);
    LOGGER.trace("lowest2: " + lowest2);
    LOGGER.trace("newPage " + pdf.getNewPage());
    /*if(pdf.getNewPage()) {
        return lowest1 > lowest2 ? lowest2 : lowest1;
      }
    */
    /*for (float y : ys) {
        if (y < result) {
        result = y;
        }
        }*/
    return lowest1 > lowest2 && pdf.getNewPage() ? lowest1 : lowest2;
    //return lowest1;
}
```

The methods where I get String value of the objects and check if they're null or empty:

```
private boolean nullOrEmpty(String s) {
    return s == null || s.isEmpty();
}

private String getStringValue(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        return "";
    }
    return getStringValue(o, null);
}

private String getStringValue(Object o, Class< ? extends Unit> clazz) {
    if (o instanceof Boolean) {
        Boolean bd = (Boolean) o;
        if (bd) {
        return constants.getString("dbeditorYes");
        } else {
        return constants.getString("dbeditorNo");
        }
    } else if (o instanceof Date) {
        Date date = (Date) o;
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(DateConstants.DATE_FORMAT);
        return df.format(date);
    } else if (o instanceof Enum) {
        Enum en = (Enum) o;
        return constants.enumMap().get(en.toString());
    } else if (o instanceof Integer) {
        Integer integer = (Integer) o;
        if (clazz == null) {
        return String.valueOf(integer);
        } else {
        Unit entry = unitSvc.get(clazz, integer);
        String[] params = entry.toString().split("\\|");
        String label = params.length == 1 ? params[0] : params[1];
        return label;
        }
    } else if (o instanceof BigDecimal) {
        BigDecimal bd = (BigDecimal) o;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0");
        df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
        return df.format(bd);
    } else if (o instanceof Float) {
        Float bd = (Float) o;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0");
        df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
        return df.format(bd);
    } else if (o instanceof String) {
        String td = (String) o;
        return td;
    }
    return "";
}
```

All of the above methods correspond to `PdfEndorsement` class.

And this is `PdfRenderingEndorsement` class which is the class where actually the data is painted (this is the complete class since all methods are used):

```
public class PdfRenderingEndorsement {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.
    getLogger(PdfRenderingEndorsement.class);

    private static final float BOTTOM_MARGIN = 60;

    private static final int DESC_WIDTH = 269; //For description fields

    private static final int FIELD_WIDTH = 70;

    private static final int FIELD_WIDTH2 = 60;

    private static final int FIELD_WIDTH3 = 60;

    private static final int FIELD1 = 112;

    private static final int VALUE1 = 112;

    private static final int FIELD2 = 80;

    private static final int VALUE2 = 80;

    private static final int VALUE_WIDTH = 80;

    private static final int VALUE_WIDTH2 = 60;

    private static final int VALUE_WIDTH3 = 80;

    private static final int HALF_WIDTH = 325;

    private static final int TEXT_WIDTH = 410; //For text fields

    private final RwaConstants constants = ConstantsGetter.getInstance();

    private final PDDocument doc;

    private final String logoPath;

    private final String[] header;

    private int count = 0;

    private boolean newPage;

    private PDPageContentStream content;

    /**
     * Empty constructor. Used only to initialize the rendering class and call
     * it's methods.
     */
    public PdfRenderingEndorsement(PDDocument doc, String logoPath, 
                   String[] header) {
    this.doc = doc;
    this.logoPath = logoPath;
    this.header = header;
    }

    public float checkContentStream2(float y, int lines, int space) 
    throws Exception {
    float newY = checkYCoord2(y, lines, space);
    if (newY == 700) {
        if (content != null) {
        content.close();
        }

        File file = new File(logoPath);
        PDJpeg logoImg = new PDJpeg(doc, new FileInputStream(file));
        PDPage page = new PDPage(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_LETTER);
        doc.addPage(page);
        content = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
        content.drawImage(logoImg, 50, 720);
        rHeader();
    }
    return newY;
    }

    private float checkYCoord2(float y, int lines, int space) {
    float newY = y;
    for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
        if ((newY - space) <= BOTTOM_MARGIN) {
        newY = 700f;
        return newY;
        } else {
        newY = newY - space;
        }
    }
    return y;
    }

    public boolean getNewPage() {
    return newPage;
    }

    public float checkContentStream(float y) throws Exception {
    float newY = checkYCoord(y, 1, 10);
    if (newY == 700) {
        if (content != null) {
        content.close();
        }
        File file = new File(logoPath);
        PDJpeg logoImg = new PDJpeg(doc, new FileInputStream(file));
        PDPage page = new PDPage(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_LETTER);
        doc.addPage(page);
        content = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
        content.drawImage(logoImg, 50, 720);
        rHeader();
    }
    return newY;
    }

    public float checkYCoord(float y, int lines, int space) {
    float newY = y;
    for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
        if ((newY - space) <= BOTTOM_MARGIN) {
        newY = 700f;
        return newY;
        } else {
        newY = newY - space;
        }
    }
    return y;
    }

    public float checkContentStream(float y, int lines, int space) 
    throws Exception {
    float newY = checkYCoord(y, lines, space);
    if (newY == 700) {
        if (content != null) {
        content.close();
        }
        File file = new File(logoPath);
        PDJpeg logoImg = new PDJpeg(doc, new FileInputStream(file));
        PDPage page = new PDPage(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_LETTER);
        doc.addPage(page);
        content = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
        content.drawImage(logoImg, 50, 720);
        rHeader();
    }
    return newY;
    }

    public void closeContentStream() throws Exception {
    if (content != null) {
        content.close();
    }
    }

    /**
     * Renders the header for slip documents.
     */
    public void rHeader() throws Exception {
    float y = 760f;
    content.setLineWidth(.5f);
    content.setFont(PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 9);
    content.setNonStrokingColor(Color.GRAY);
    content.drawLine(50, 710, 562, 710);

    y = rText(150, y + 19, 10, constants.endorsement(), null,
          TEXT_WIDTH, 0);
    y = rText(150, y + 9, 10, header[0], null, TEXT_WIDTH, 0);
    y = rText(150, y + 9, 10, header[1], null, TEXT_WIDTH, 0);
    y = rText(150, y + 9, 10, header[2], null, TEXT_WIDTH, 0);
    y = rText(150, y + 9, 10, header[3], null, TEXT_WIDTH, 0);
    content.setNonStrokingColor(Color.BLACK);
    content.setFont(PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 9);
    }

    public float rText(float x, float y, int space, String labelField,
               String value) 
    throws Exception {
    return rText(x, y, space, labelField, value, FIELD_WIDTH, 
             HALF_WIDTH - 2 * FIELD_WIDTH - 10);    
    }

    public float rTextLR(float x, float y, int space, String labelField,
               String value) 
    throws Exception {
    return rText(x, y, space, labelField, value, 0, 
             HALF_WIDTH - 2 * FIELD_WIDTH - 10);    
    }

    public float rText(float x, float y, int space, String labelField,
               String value, int fieldWidth) 
    throws Exception {
    if (fieldWidth == 0) {
        return rText(x, y, space, labelField, value, FIELD_WIDTH2, 
             VALUE_WIDTH2);
    } else if (fieldWidth == 1) {
        return rText(x, y, space, labelField, value, FIELD_WIDTH3,
             VALUE_WIDTH3);
    } else if (fieldWidth == 2) {
        return rText(x, y, space, labelField, value, TEXT_WIDTH,
             TEXT_WIDTH);
    }
    return y;
    }


    public float getFieldSize(int fs) {
    switch(fs) {
    case 1:
        return (FIELD_WIDTH + VALUE_WIDTH);
    case 2:
        return (FIELD_WIDTH + DESC_WIDTH);
    case 3:
        return (FIELD_WIDTH + TEXT_WIDTH);
    case 4:
        return (HALF_WIDTH - FIELD_WIDTH);
    case 5:
        return (FIELD_WIDTH + TEXT_WIDTH);
    case 6:
        return (FIELD_WIDTH + TEXT_WIDTH);
    case 7:
        return (FIELD1 + 19) / 2;
    case 8:
        return (FIELD2 + 19) / 2;
    default:
        return 0;
    }
    }

    public void paintLinesH(float y) throws Exception {
    content.drawLine(49, y - 6, 327, y - 6);
    content.drawLine(335, y - 6, 563, y - 6);
    }

    public void paintLinesV(float x, float yMax, float yMin)
    throws Exception {
    content.drawLine(x - 1, yMax - 6, x - 1, yMin - 6);
    }

    public float rText(float x, float y, int space, String labelField,
               String value, int fieldWidth, int valueWidth) 
    throws Exception {
    PDFont font = PDType1Font.TIMES_BOLD;
    content.setFont(font, 9);
    float y1 = 0f;
    float y2 = 0f;
    if (value == null) {
        return rText(labelField, fieldWidth, x, y - 19, space, font, false);
    } else {
        if (labelField == null) {
        font = PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN;
        content.setFont(font, 9);
        return rText(value, valueWidth, x, y - 19, space, font, true);
        } else {
        y1 = rText(labelField, fieldWidth, x, y - 30, space, font, 
               false);
        font = PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN;
        content.setFont(font, 9);
        float y3 = y;
        y2 = rText(value, valueWidth, x + fieldWidth + 10, y - 30,
               space, font, true);
        if (y3 < y2) {
            return y2;
        } else {
            if (y1 >= y2) {
            return y2;
            } else {
            return y1;
            }
        }
        }
    }
    }

    private ArrayList<String> getRows(String text, int width, PDFont font)
    throws Exception {
    float textWidth = font.getStringWidth(text) / 1000f * 9f;
    ArrayList<String> result = Lists.newArrayList();
    if (textWidth < width) {
        result.add(text);
        return result;
    }

    float spaceWidth = font.getStringWidth(" ") / 1000f * 9f;
    String[] paragraphs = text.split("\n|\r\n|\r");
    for (String paragraph : paragraphs) {
        float pWidth = font.getStringWidth(paragraph) / 1000f * 9f;
        if (pWidth < width) {
        result.add(paragraph);
        continue;
        }

        float widthCount = 0f;
        String[] words = paragraph.trim().split(" ");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
        if (words[j].trim().length() == 0) {
            continue;
        }

        float wWidth = font.getStringWidth(words[j]) / 1000f * 9f;
        float totalWidth = widthCount + wWidth + spaceWidth;
        if (totalWidth < width + spaceWidth) {
            sb.append(words[j]);
            sb.append(" ");
            widthCount = totalWidth;
        } else {
            result.add(sb.toString().trim());
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(words[j]);
            sb.append(" ");
            widthCount = totalWidth - widthCount;
        }
        }
        result.add(sb.toString().trim());
    }
    return result;
    }

    private float rText(String text, int width, float x, float y, int space,
            PDFont font, boolean isValue) throws Exception {
    float newY = y;
    int rowHeight = 0;
    newPage = false;
    ArrayList<String> rowList = getRows(text, width, font);
    if (isValue) {
        for (String row : rowList) {
        if (rowHeight >= 10) {
            newY = checkContentStream(newY - 10);
            newY = newY == 700 ? 680 : newY;
            if (newY <= 700 && !newPage) {
            newPage = true;
            }
            rowHeight = newY == 680 ? 0 : rowHeight;
        }
        content.beginText();
        content.moveTextPositionByAmount(x, newY);
        content.drawString(row);
        content.endText();
        rowHeight = rowHeight + 10;
        }
    } else {
        for (String row : rowList) {
        content.beginText();
        content.moveTextPositionByAmount(x, newY - rowHeight);
        content.drawString(row);
        content.endText();
        rowHeight = rowHeight + 10;
        }
        newY -= (rowHeight - 10);
    }
    return newY;
    }
}
```

This is a [PDF Example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-z424N1EYicR1BxUUtUSkw4V1U/view?usp=sharing) of the output with the original (`for-each`) method.

If you can't see the PDF let me know but here are also some Screenshots from it:

[image]

This is a [PDF Example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-z424N1EYicTGdobnlqWHFvLXc/view?usp=sharing) of the output with the non-commented code on `getMinY` method.

And from this modification here's the output:

[image]

As you can see the 1st output "jumps" into the next page, because let's say the text on the right on "Texto de Poliza" ended on Y coord 680, 670 or something like that but on the left I painted an empty field `("")` which ended in 90 or 100 something near of those numbers.

Then it compares 100 < 670 ? Yes, then I take 50 to 100 and it's lower than my `BOTTOM_MARGIN` (which is 60), so it closes actual page (which is now where the text ended but thinks it's on the page before it) and creates a new one.

I've asked a similar question almost a year before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774668/pdf-issue-while-reaching-end-of-page), these Classes are almost a copy from those files but this bug on my logic comes only with these files because data is handled a bit different.

Well after that wall of text I hope someone could read it and actually give me a hand, maybe I'm missing an important part but can't find it atm.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

After adding @mkl's answer to my methods I find that when no information changed in both sides, it creates a gap and it doesn't look good.

[image]

This is how I'm sending data to `PdfRenderingEndorsementAlternative`:

```
for (String[] data: sOppData) {
        //float y = renderer.getPreviousBandBase;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length - 2; i += 3) {
            if (!nullOrEmpty(data[i + 1]) &&
                !nullOrEmpty(data[i + 2])) {
                if (!data[i + 1].equals(data[i + 2])) {
                renderer.
                    render(new BandColumn(leftHalfPageField,
                              data[i], data[i + 1]),
                       new BandColumn(rightHalfPageField,
                              data[i], data[i + 2])
                       );
                }
            } else if (nullOrEmpty(data[i + 1]) &&
                   !nullOrEmpty(data[i + 2])) {
                renderer.
                render(new BandColumn(leftHalfPageField, 
                              "", ""),
                       new BandColumn(rightHalfPageField,
                              data[i], data[i + 2])
                       );
            } else if (!nullOrEmpty(data[i + 1]) &&
                   nullOrEmpty(data[i + 2])) {
                renderer.
                render(new BandColumn(leftHalfPageField,
                              data[i], data[i + 1]),
                       new BandColumn(rightHalfPageField,
                              "", "")
                       );
            }
        }
        //float y2 = renderer.getPreviousBandBase();
        /*if (y2 < y) 
            renderer.gap(20);
        */
        renderer.gap(20); 
  }
```

Are the above commented validations correct or would I be going back to past methods that originated bugs? Should I add `getPreviousBandBase()` method on *PdfRenderingEndorsementAlternative* or think in another way to do it directly on `render()` method?

And this is how I get data that currently has the same info in both sides.

An example of this would be:

`sOppA.getContractName()` and `sOppE.getContractName()` are both `"Hello World"` and as both are equal then it would leave a gap as seen on screenshot.

```
private ArrayList<String []> renderSubscriptionOpportunity(
               SubscriptionOpp sOppA, SubscriptionOpp sOppE, 
               ArrayList<Location> lcA, ArrayList<Location> lcE) 
    throws Exception {
    ArrayList <String[]> sOppData = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    sOppData.add(new String[] {constants.currencyId(),
                   getStringValue(sOppA.getCurrencyId(), 
                          Currency.class),
                   getStringValue(sOppE.getCurrencyId(),
                          Currency.class)});

    sOppData.add(new String[] {constants.contractName(),
                   getStringValue(sOppA.getContractName()),
                   getStringValue(sOppE.getContractName())});

    sOppData.add(new String[] {constants.mainActivityId(),
                   getStringValue(sOppA.getMainActivityId(),
                          MainActivity.class),
                   getStringValue(sOppE.getMainActivityId(),
                          MainActivity.class)});

    //here add location table

    if (lcA.size() > 1 && lcE.size() > 1) {
        int lastIdA = 0;
        int lastIdE = 0;
        int size = lcA.size() >= lcE.size() ? lcA.size() : lcE.size();

        LOGGER.trace("size: " + size + " lcA.size(): " + lcA.size() +
             " lcE.size(): " + lcE.size());
        for (int pos = 1; pos < lcA.size(); pos++) {
        StringBuilder aSb = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder eSb = new StringBuilder();
        String valueA = "";
        String valueE = "";
        if (pos < lcA.size()) {
            Country countryA = unitSvc.get(Country.class, 
                           lcA.get(pos).getCountryId());
            LOGGER.trace("Entro1");
            if (countryA.getId() != lastIdA) {
            aSb.append(countryA.getName());
            lastIdA = countryA.getId();
            } else {
            aSb.append("");
            }
        } else {
            aSb.append("");
        }       
        if (pos < lcE.size()) {
            Country countryE = unitSvc.get(Country.class, 
                           lcE.get(pos).getCountryId());
            LOGGER.trace("Entro2");
            if (countryE.getId() != lastIdE) {
            eSb.append(countryE.getName());
            lastIdE = countryE.getId();
            } else {
            eSb.append("");
            }
        } else {
            eSb.append("");
        }
        valueA = aSb.toString();
        valueE = eSb.toString();
        sOppData.add(new String[] {pos == 1 ? constants.countryId() : 
                       "", valueA, valueE});
        }
    }
    return sOppData;
}
```

Comment: As I already commented on your former question, *i doubt it is a good idea to check* for page switches *from inside rtext at all,* it should be controlled by some method with an eye on the content to add for the current entry in **all** columns.

Comment: @mkl do you have an example maybe a link to another question of that method? Or something similar which I could analyze? And sorry for late answer. Thanks. I'll be reading some docs and try some methods by now. I'm not that experienced with programming pdf so I make a lot of mistakes (I don't know how to do a simple "Hello World" with pdf, I mean not from 0)

Comment: I've started reading how to start a PDF from 0 with PDFBox and Maven, I'm still stuck on Maven Config but once I have an MCVE I'll post it.

Comment: You do `renderer.gap(20);` each time in your for loop, not caring whether you rendered an entry or not. Only add a gap after rendering an entry.

Comment: how couldn't I see that before? I was thinking of an `else { continue }` for the `if(!data[i+1].equals(data[i+2])` I'll test it on Monday...

Comment: `else { continue }` does not suffice because in the first if-block you don't necessarily render something. I would propose simply to always throw in a gap right after each `renderer.render` call and not try to optimize when confronted with non-trivial control flows.

Comment: Have you meanwhile been able to get rid of the extra gaps?

Comment: @mkl yeah, thanks you, I did it just as you said. I am now just thinking on how to draw some lines to make tables, insert more columns (which I guess is with more BandColumn when calling render method) and how not to cut table i.e. Whole table on same page.

Comment: Ah, now you start to want to have more advanced layouting features... ;) One can use the `PdfRenderingEndorsementAlternative ` as a base for that but move rendering into `BandColumn` or even `Layout` (to allow for more specific rendering variants). As you already guessed, more columns are possible using more `BandColumn` arguments (and some more `Layout` definitions). And pagebreaks in a band can be prevented by a small change of the rendering code in its current form.

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna try today once I arrive office, and when I have something (or get stuck) reply here and add code. I haven't fully understood how your code works at all, I've been migrating from last methods to the current ones :) and maybe not prevent page brake but force it onto the next page, depending on table size

Comment: It would be better if you started by listing a set of features you (realistically) would like to use. With that list in mind, you can create an architecture which allows for natural integration of such feature into your code (they need not be implemented from the start but as soon as you want to implement them, they fit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already hinted at in a comment (actually already in a comment to your [former question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774668/pdf-issue-while-reaching-end-of-page)) I think that the whole architecture of your rendering class needs an overhaul. Based on your `PdfRenderingEndorsement` I created the following class `PdfRenderingEndorsementAlternative` which represents an alternative approach at that rendering:

```
public class PdfRenderingEndorsementAlternative implements AutoCloseable
{
    //
    // misc constants
    //
    static final int FIELD_WIDTH = 70;
    static final int HALF_WIDTH = 325;
    static final int TEXT_WIDTH = 410;

    static final float BOTTOM_MARGIN = 70;
    static final int LEFT_MARGIN = 50;

    //
    // rendering
    //
    public void gap(int size)
    {
        previousBandBase-=size;
    }

    public void render(BandColumn... columns) throws IOException
    {
        if (content == null)
            newPage();

        final List<Chunk> chunks = new ArrayList<Chunk>();
        for (BandColumn column : columns)
        {
            chunks.addAll(column.toChunks());
        }

        float offset = 0;
        while (!chunks.isEmpty())
        {
            float lowestAddedY = previousBandBase;
            float highestBaseBeforeNonAdded = Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
            List<Chunk> added = new ArrayList<Chunk>();
            for (Chunk chunk: chunks)
            {
                float y = previousBandBase + chunk.y + offset; 
                if (y >= BOTTOM_MARGIN)
                {
                    content.beginText();
                    content.setFont(chunk.font, 9);
                    content.moveTextPositionByAmount(chunk.x, y);
                    content.drawString(chunk.text);
                    content.endText();
                    // draw
                    if (y < lowestAddedY)
                        lowestAddedY = y;
                    added.add(chunk);
                }
                else
                {
                    float baseBefore = chunk.y + chunk.space;
                    if (baseBefore > highestBaseBeforeNonAdded)
                        highestBaseBeforeNonAdded = baseBefore;
                }
            }
            chunks.removeAll(added);
            if (!chunks.isEmpty())
            {
                newPage();
                offset = -highestBaseBeforeNonAdded;
            }
            else
            {
                previousBandBase = lowestAddedY;
            }
        }
    }

    static public class BandColumn
    {
        public enum Layout
        {
            headerText(150, TEXT_WIDTH, 0, 10),
            leftHalfPageField(LEFT_MARGIN, FIELD_WIDTH, HALF_WIDTH - 2 * FIELD_WIDTH - 10, 10),
            rightHalfPageField(HALF_WIDTH, FIELD_WIDTH, HALF_WIDTH - 2 * FIELD_WIDTH - 10, 10);

            Layout(float x, int fieldWidth, int valueWidth, int space)
            {
                this.x = x;
                this.fieldWidth = fieldWidth;
                this.valueWidth = valueWidth;
                this.space = space;
            }

            final float x;
            final int fieldWidth, valueWidth, space;
        }

        public BandColumn(Layout layout, String labelField, String value)
        {
            this(layout.x, layout.space, labelField, value, layout.fieldWidth, layout.valueWidth);
        }

        public BandColumn(float x, int space, String labelField, String value, int fieldWidth, int valueWidth)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.space = space;
            this.labelField = labelField;
            this.value = value;
            this.fieldWidth = fieldWidth;
            this.valueWidth = valueWidth;
        }

        List<Chunk> toChunks() throws IOException
        {
            final List<Chunk> result = new ArrayList<Chunk>();
            result.addAll(toChunks(0, fieldWidth, PDType1Font.TIMES_BOLD, labelField));
            result.addAll(toChunks(10 + fieldWidth, valueWidth, PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN, value));
            return result;
        }

        List<Chunk> toChunks(int offset, int width, PDFont font, String text) throws IOException
        {
            if (text == null || text.length() == 0)
                return Collections.emptyList();

            final List<Chunk> result = new ArrayList<Chunk>();
            float y = -space;
            List<String> rows = getRows(text, width, font);
            for (String row: rows)
            {
                result.add(new Chunk(x+offset, y, space, font, row));
                y-= space;
            }
            return result;
        }

        final float x;
        final int space, fieldWidth, valueWidth;
        final String labelField, value;
    }

    //
    // constructor
    //
    public PdfRenderingEndorsementAlternative(PDDocument doc, InputStream logo, 
            String[] header) throws IOException
    {
        this.doc = doc;
        this.header = header;
        logoImg = new PDJpeg(doc, logo);
    }

    //
    // AutoCloseable implementation
    //
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException
    {
        if (content != null)
        {
            content.close();
            content = null;
        }
    }

    //
    // helper methods
    //
    void newPage() throws IOException
    {
        close();

        PDPage page = new PDPage(PDPage.PAGE_SIZE_LETTER);
        doc.addPage(page);
        content = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
        content.drawImage(logoImg, 50, 720);
        content.setLineWidth(.5f);
        content.setNonStrokingColor(Color.GRAY);
        content.drawLine(50, 710, 562, 710);

        previousBandBase = 770;
        render(new BandColumn(BandColumn.Layout.headerText, "ENDOSO", null));
        for (String head: header)
            render(new BandColumn(BandColumn.Layout.headerText, head, null));

        content.setNonStrokingColor(Color.BLACK);
        previousBandBase = 680;
    }

    // original method
    static List<String> getRows(String text, int width, PDFont font) throws IOException
    {
        float textWidth = font.getStringWidth(text) / 1000f * 9f;
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();// Lists.newArrayList();
        if (textWidth < width)
        {
            result.add(text);
            return result;
        }

        float spaceWidth = font.getStringWidth(" ") / 1000f * 9f;
        String[] paragraphs = text.split("\n|\r\n|\r");
        for (String paragraph : paragraphs)
        {
            float pWidth = font.getStringWidth(paragraph) / 1000f * 9f;
            if (pWidth < width)
            {
                result.add(paragraph);
                continue;
            }

            float widthCount = 0f;
            String[] words = paragraph.trim().split(" ");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++)
            {
                if (words[j].trim().length() == 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                float wWidth = font.getStringWidth(words[j]) / 1000f * 9f;
                float totalWidth = widthCount + wWidth + spaceWidth;
                if (totalWidth < width + spaceWidth)
                {
                    sb.append(words[j]);
                    sb.append(" ");
                    widthCount = totalWidth;
                }
                else
                {
                    result.add(sb.toString().trim());
                    sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.append(words[j]);
                    sb.append(" ");
                    widthCount = totalWidth - widthCount;
                }
            }
            result.add(sb.toString().trim());
        }
        return result;
    }

    //
    // helper classes
    //
    static class Chunk
    {
        Chunk(float x, float y, int space, PDFont font, String text)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.space = space;
            this.font = font;
            this.text = text;
        }

        final float x, y;
        final int space;
        final PDFont font;
        final String text;
    }

    //
    // members
    //
    private final PDDocument doc;
    private final PDJpeg logoImg;
    private final String[] header;

    private PDPageContentStream content = null;
    private float previousBandBase = 0;
}
```

> *([PdfRenderingEndorsementAlternative.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox1/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox1/content/PdfRenderingEndorsementAlternative.java))*

This class is based on the concept of bands, i.e. horizontal stripes of content, with any number of columns containing field names and / or field values.

It can be used like this:

```
PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
PdfRenderingEndorsementAlternative renderer = new PdfRenderingEndorsementAlternative(document, logoStream, header);

renderer.render(
        new BandColumn(leftHalfPageField, "Nombre del contrato/asegurado:", "Prueba Jesus Fac No Prop"),
        new BandColumn(rightHalfPageField, "Nombre del contrato/asegurado:", "Prueba Jesus Fac No Prop con Endoso")
        );

renderer.gap(20);

renderer.render(
        new BandColumn(leftHalfPageField, "País:", "México"),
        new BandColumn(rightHalfPageField, "País:", "México")
        );

renderer.close();
document.save(new File(RESULT_FOLDER, "Endorsement.pdf"));
```

> *([RenderEndorsement.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox1/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox1/content/RenderEndorsement.java))*

As you see, the caller does not have to care anymore about y positions, everything is done in the renderer class. And the result:

[image: the result]

I used the data from your first sample PDF as input, and this is the result:

[image: result for sample data]

As you see, no page jumps and no overlapping texts, either.

Comment: I'm testing the solution, I took me a while to adapt it to the project, would you mind if I start a bounty in 4 hours (missing time until I can add it) and on Weekend accept your answer so you get the bounty? Btw thank you a lot, seeing the method I guess I was trying to reinvent the wheel (and in a wrong way). I'll keep trying to configure Maven anyway to make a project from 0 and learn how to do MCVE for PDF's in a future.

Comment: *would you mind if ...* - I would not mind but please don't feel obliged to do so. I hope this code sample can help you.

Comment: Of course it's helping me. I don't feel obligated but grateful. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I have a doubt, where would you check if something hasn't changed in both sides?, i.e it creates a gap of 20 even if no information has changed. I was thinking on taking current Y and end Y but I guess I'd be going back into my method and that would bring some more bugs.

Comment: I edited question with updated methods... Hmm guess I found my error, I've added all data even if it hasn't changed, I was trying to reduce code lines that way but that won't be possible I guess. I'll check that on Monday. I have 3 possible ways to solve it in my mind right now. If any works I'll be updating it

Comment: *I've added all data even if it hasn't changed* - especially you added a gap independent of whether or not there was no difference