# How to generate Dyanamic no of pages using PDFBOX

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I have to generate a pdf file depending on some input .Each time the code runs , the input length may vary , so how can I add pages to the document dynamically depending on my input content .

```
public class pdfproject
     {
      static int lineno=768;
      public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception 
       {
        PDDocument doc= new PDDocument();
        PDPage page = new PDPage();
        doc.addPage(page);
        PDPageContentStream cos = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
        for(int i=0;i<2000;i++)
         {           
           renderText("hello"+i,cos,60);
         }
        cos.close();
        doc.save("test.pdf");
        doc.close();
     }

       static void renderText(String Info,PDPageContentStream cos,int marginwidth) throws Exception
    {
         lineno-=12;    
         System.out.print("lineno="+lineno);
         PDFont fontPlain = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
         cos.beginText();
         cos.setFont(fontPlain, 10);
         cos.moveTextPositionByAmount(marginwidth,lineno);
         cos.drawString(Info);
         cos.endText();
     }
     }
```

How do i ensure that the content is rendered on the next page by adding a new page dynamically when there is no space on the current page ?

Comment: Pdfbox does not include any automatic layouting support. Thus, you have to keep track of how full a page is (e.g. by testing `lineno`), and you have to close the current page, create a new one, reset fill indicators, etc.

Comment: yes , the new page should get generated when (lineno>0 && lineno<12) condition is met. I am trying to figure out  how would i add a new page to the document dynamically when the above condition is met.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pdfbox does not include any automatic layouting support. Thus, you have to keep track of how full a page is, and you have to close the current page, create a new one, reset fill indicators, etc

This obviously should not be done in static members in some project class but instead in some dedicated class and its instance members. E.g.

```
public class PdfRenderingSimple implements AutoCloseable
{
    //
    // rendering
    //
    public void renderText(String Info, int marginwidth) throws IOException
    {
        if (content == null || textRenderingLineY < 12)
            newPage();

        textRenderingLineY-=12;    
        System.out.print("lineno=" + textRenderingLineY);
        PDFont fontPlain = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
        content.beginText();
        content.setFont(fontPlain, 10);
        content.moveTextPositionByAmount(marginwidth, textRenderingLineY);
        content.drawString(Info);
        content.endText();
    }

    //
    // constructor
    //
    public PdfRenderingSimple(PDDocument doc)
    {
        this.doc = doc;
    }

    //
    // AutoCloseable implementation
    //
    /**
     * Closes the current page
     */
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException
    {
        if (content != null)
        {
            content.close();
            content = null;
        }
    }

    //
    // helper methods
    //
    void newPage() throws IOException
    {
        close();

        PDPage page = new PDPage();
        doc.addPage(page);
        content = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
        content.setNonStrokingColor(Color.BLACK);

        textRenderingLineY = 768;
    }

    //
    // members
    //
    final PDDocument doc;

    private PDPageContentStream content = null;
    private int textRenderingLineY = 0;
}
```

> *([PdfRenderingSimple.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox1/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox1/content/PdfRenderingSimple.java))*

You can use it like this

```
PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();

PdfRenderingSimple renderer = new PdfRenderingSimple(doc);
for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
{
    renderer.renderText("hello" + i, 60);
}
renderer.close();

doc.save(new File("renderSimple.pdf"));
doc.close();
```

> *([RenderSimple.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox1/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox1/content/RenderSimple.java))*

For more specialized rendering support you will implement improved rendering classes, e.g. [PdfRenderingEndorsementAlternative.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox1/blob/master/src/main/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox1/content/PdfRenderingEndorsementAlternative.java) from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30801513/1729265).

Comment: @mkl, Its been 7 years for this answer. Is it still applicable or do we have some better solution possible via recent updates in `PDFBox`.

Comment: @ScrapCode *"Is it still applicable or do we have some better solution possible via recent updates"* - see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72518886/1729265) to [your recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72517080/1729265): PDFBox itself still has no built-in layout feature for the text body content but there are third-party libraries offering some layout features.