# Java PDFBOX writing to pages beyond first page

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am writing a Java program that reads in a CSV file and then writes out the information in a certain format into a PDF.  I am using Java 12.0.2+10 and PDFBOX-app-2.0.22 in Apache NetBeans 12.0.  After much study I've learned the basics and have my program working well for 1 paged  documents.  The problem comes if my content exceeds the space on page 1.  Then I need to create a new page, add it to the document, and then create a new content stream for page2.  The name of the content stream must be different than it was in page 1 as that variable name has already been used.  This requires me to duplicate, but with the new content stream name, the code used for page 1 that formats & displays the text, lines, etc..  If my content exceeds 2 pages, I have to create a third page and again duplicate all the code that formats and shows the text.  This makes for very large and difficult to maintain code.   **Is not there is a way to make the content stream name a variable so that I can have one code block to write to the different pages in my document?**

```
PDDocument doc = new PDDocument(); // creating instance of PDFdoc
PDPage page1 = new PDPage(PDRectangle.LETTER); 
        doc.addPage(page1);  
        PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream(doc,page1); 
content.beginText();

for(int I = 0; I < lineCount; i++){

// code to format text
content.setFont(fontBold,fontSize10);
content.newLineAtOffset(leftMargin, pageHeight - marginTop - page1HeaderHeight - (pageLineCount * lineSpacing10));
content.showText(“text to display”); // display the text

etc...
content.endText();

content.close(); // closes content stream for page 1
}



// page 2 code block
PDPage page2 = new PDPage(PDRectangle.LETTER); // set page size to 8.5 x 11.0" = US letter
doc.addPage(page2);  // adding a page in PDF file
PDPageContentStream content2 = new PDPageContentStream(doc,page2,AppendMode.APPEND, true, true);
           
content2.beginText();
content2.setFont(fontBold,fontSize10);
content2.newLineAtOffset(leftMargin, pageHeight - marginTop - page1HeaderHeight - (pageLineCount * lineSpacing10));
content.showText(“text to display”); // display the text

etc...

content2.endText(); 
content.2close(); // closes content stream for page 2
```

Comment: The answer is "no", you need to use a second loop that creates a new page when the current one is full.

Comment: This one may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30882927/