# Print multiple pages using PDFBox

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I have a list of text data containing links (`PDActions`) that might need to be rendered on more than one page. (see below)

```
                **Table of Contents**
document1 link                          5
document2 link                          8
document3 link                          11
```

Is there a simple way to just print all these content and let `PDFBox` decide to wrap the text and fit them in multiple pages as needed. And just give me the final `PDDocument`?

There are multiple answers on this topic such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30888656/3048967) one. However, the answers are quite old, and I'm checking if there is a newer and simpler way to do it.

`PDFBox` version: 2.0.26

Answer (score 1):

PDFBox essentially still only has that very low-level text drawing API but there are projects built on top of PDFBox offering automatic layout.

Allow me to quote the [PDFBox FAQs](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html#can-i-use-pdfbox-to-create-complex-layouts%3F)

> #### Can I use PDFBox to create complex layouts?
>
> I'd like to use PDFBox to create a complex layout containing several paragraphs, tables, images etc. Is PDFBox fit for that purpose?
>
> PDFBox being a low level PDF library provides the APIs to create page content such as text, images etc. But at this point in time it doesn't provide a higher level API to do page layout, paragraph handling, automatic line wrapping or create tables and such.
>
> But PDFBox is the foundation of some projects which might help in that case. This includes projects such as
>
> - [Boxable](http://dhorions.github.io/boxable/)
> - [BoxTable](https://github.com/errt/BoxTable)
> - [easytable](https://github.com/vandeseer/easytable)
> - [pdfbox-layout](https://github.com/ralfstuckert/pdfbox-layout)
> - [PdfLayoutManager](https://github.com/GlenKPeterson/PdfLayoutManager)
> - [ph-pdf-layout](https://github.com/phax/ph-pdf-layout)
>
> You may also want to consider using Apache FOP which allows to create complex documents from XML data and templates-