# Absolute text position in PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm trying to create a pdf document in java using the PDFBox libraries and for now, I am positioning the text using `newLineAtOffset(x, y);` but I would prefer to position using an absolute position, rather than the relative.

Is there any way to use an absolute position or a have to stay with the relative one?

Thank you in advance for any help you can give me

Comment: Not sure if it's what you're looking for but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30801513/2180785) is something related about positioning text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are starting at (0,0) after calling `contents.beginText();`. Thus if you want to work with absolute positions only, then put only one (absolute) positioning in a `contents.beginText();` … `contents.endText();` segment.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of that. Thank you very much!